# Is it possible to install components after installation in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I have an unreliable internet connection, so I figured I would install VS2015 from an ISO file, but that file doesn't have every components included that I need. Is it possible to install components like Xamarin after the install?

Answer (score 1):

I found it in Tools (not Service) > Extensions and Updates > Get Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Service > Extensions and updates> Get Xamarin)